# What is the ruling on having a "professorial" beard?

Tags: halal-haram, men, beard

I am aware that it is Haram to be clean-shaven and Muslim men ought not to shave their beard completely, but I'd like to know if it is Haram to shave the beard like "professorial beard".

I mean a kind of beard which as far as I know, this is famous as professorial beard. At least this is famous in my country (Iran) with this name. It consists a kind of the beard that you keep the beards which are around the mouth (relatively similar to a circle) and then shave the rest of the beards. Actually is it counted as the bread or not?

Answer (score 2):

Salaam

This not called beard which you mention in your question.

Beard is called beard when you do not clean hairs on your face at certain limits. This means beard on your face is started from ears till your chin and it also goes down to neck (not full neck but a half which is proper), this does not count the area of right and left side of your nose.

The beard length is also defined which is "You can grow it till you can hold it in your hand and not grater then that" If a person from 40 steps away say "oh you have beard" then it's called beard.

Regards,

Comment: Haidar, tis a logical response. yeah, you are right. Of course I wish you add a hadith to your answer as well.

Comment: This is one definition. I think there are other definitions of what a beard is though.

Answer (score 1):

Beard - you should have a minimum of one hand of beard. If it is less than that, it is just a hair not shaven but not a beard.